# Could not find an overload for '-' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift

I am just playing around with Swift for the first time and I do not understand why this does not work. Any help would be great!

I get the error **could not find an overload for '-' that accepts the supplied arguments**

for the line that says **self.health = self.health - amount**

```
class human {
    var name:String
    var height:Integer
    var hairColor:String
    var health:Integer

    init(name:String, height:Integer, hairColor:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.hairColor = hairColor
        self.health = 100
    }

    func applyDamage(amount:Integer) -> Integer{
        self.health = self.health - amount
        return self.health
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Int`, not `Integer`.

`Integer` is a protocol, not the type.

Answer (score 3):

To explain the actual error message, Swift is trying to apply the '-' operator to an **Integer** and an **Integer**, but you have not overloaded the '-' operator. This is why the error is worded as it is. The '-' operators works in the case of an **Int** and an **Int**, which was obviously your intention in this instance, so you simply need to use **Int** instead of **Integer**

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth, you might want to do

```
self.health -= amount
```

instead of

```
self.health = self.health - amount
```

to be more idiomatic

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have meant to use Int instead of Integer. This code works fine:

```
class human {
    var name:String
    var height:Int
    var hairColor:String
    var health:Int

    init(name:String, height:Int, hairColor:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.hairColor = hairColor
        self.health = 100
    }

    func applyDamage(amount:Int) -> Int{
        self.health = self.health - amount
        return self.health
    }
}
```