# Multiplying integers

Tags: swift

I am certain I am missing something very, very obvious, but can anyone tell me why I am having trouble multiplying two `Integers`? The following code:

```
let twenty: Integer = 20
let ten: Integer = 10
let result: Integer = twenty * ten
```

presents the error `Could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied arguments`.

Other questions on SO with the same error are caused by trying to multiply different types together, but surely these are both `Integer` types?

(PS: The actual code I am trying to run is `var value = self.value * 10` but I have expanded it to the sample while debugging to make absolutely sure that the correct types are being used)

Comment: possible duplicate of [could not find an overload for '-' that accepts the supplied arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031901/could-not-find-an-overload-for-that-accepts-the-supplied-arguments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `Int` instead. `Integer` is a protocol.

Answer (score 4):

`Integer` is a protocol not a type. Use `Int` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated , Integer is a protocol not a type .

In your situation, you don't need to do explicit the type because it is of implicit casting.

This could be enough

```
 let twenty = 20
 let ten = 10
 let result = twenty * ten

 NSLog("%d", result)
```